# После авторизации в Facebook всплывающее окно не пропадает ios9 Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

После авторизации в  Facebook, вместо того что бы просто исчезнуть и показать мое приложение, страница обновляется и остается пустой, и из выходов имеем только возможность нажать кнопку "ГОТОВО", которая отменяет авторизацию.

**UPDATE**: при проверке на прошивке iOs 8.4 все происходит нормально, и приложение самостоятельно открывается, но все равно при проверке результата он имеет состояние отмененного (result.isCencelled = true)

И так же замечено что выдается ошибка в консоли: "an active access token must be used to query information about the current user." то есть логгин ин не происходит, хотя вроде все делалось по шаблону предложенному фейсбуком.

Добавление кнопки:

```
fbButton = FBSDKLoginButton() //FACEBOOK Button
fbButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,CGFloat(width),CGFloat(91))
fbButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile","email","user_friends"]
fbButton.delegate = self
fbView.addSubview(fbButton)
```

Метод выполнения указанный делегатом:

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
    if ((error) != nil)
    {
        //handle error
        print("Houston, we have a PROBLEM")
    } else {
        returnUserData()
    }
}
```

метод для возврата пользовательских данных (сейчас используется для проверки наличия токена, который всегда отсутсвует):

```
func returnUserData()
{

    if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil){
        if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().hasGranted("email") {
            print("Houston, we have an EMAIL")
        } else {
            print("Houston, we have a PROBLEM")
        }

    } else {
        print("Houston, we even have no TOLEN")
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

EDIT: Да вот что добавлялось в plist.info:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb**********</string> // я ввел свое значение
            <string>fbauth2</string>      // без этой строки выбирало 
        </array>                          // ошибку связанную с fbauth2
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>****************</string>  // я ввел свое значение
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>EnglishFor</string>

<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>

<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Было тоже самое ) 
Надо в AppDelegate.swift добавить

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

    return ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)

}
```

Comment: Проблема у меня решилась сама, не известно почему, но спасибо за внимание!)